# Azure Data Factory - Recording file name when reading all files in folder from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a set of CSV files stored in Azure Blob Storage. 
 I am reading the files into a database table using the Copy Data task. 
 The Source is set as the folder where the files reside, so it's grabbing it's file and loading it into the database. 
 The issue is that I can't seem to map the file name in order to read it into a column. I'm sure there are more complicated ways to do it, for instance first reading the metadata and then read the files using a loop, but surely the file metadata should be available to use while traversing through the files? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in a regular copy activity. Mapping Data Flows has this possibility, it's still in preview, but maybe it can help you out. If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#source-file-management), you find an option to specify a column to store file name.

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I can't see anything in the documentation, but have requested the preview to check it out.

Comment: It's in this section of the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#source-file-management